# Need to play flash videos on iphone

Tags: iphone, flvplayback, akamai, flv

I am building this iphone app for a client and they have a large set of flash video files that they need to play/stream to the iphone. I understand that the iphone doesnt natively support flv playback but isnt there anything I can do to get around this problem?

In case it helps, they are using the akamai flash player on their website to play these video files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! - You can convert all the videos to m4v format.

Comment: but is this really the only way? i see other apps that have videos embedded. did they have to convert all their library in m4v or upload them on youtube?

Answer (score 0):

There's a javascript hack available, but it will only work if it's installed on the clients web server.  It's also pretty clunky and slow and will likely murder battery life.

A workaround, since you're working with video, is to convert to mp4 format.

Short answer: no flash, but conversion will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

akamai actually supports "auto-packaging" of h.264 content which may be your best option here.  By uploading 1 or more h.264 files you can use those to both serve your Flash player, and akamai will also auto-package them for iPhone (chunking them into .ts files and creating an .m3u8 reference file for dynamic mobile streaming).

This allows you to not have separate encodes for mobile and web, thus saving money and time so you can leverage your existing archive.

Comment: does this changes when its not individual files but a continuous stream?